# Select HTML from iframe using Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, selection

Following is a `javaScript` function to get selected content from an `iframe`

```
function getIframeSelectionText(iframe) {
    var win = iframe.contentWindow;
    var doc = win.document;

    if (win.getSelection) {
        return win.getSelection();
    } else if (doc.selection && doc.selection.createRange) {
        return doc.selection.createRange();
    }
}
```

The Sample `iframe` looks like this:

```
<iframe id="iframeId" type="html" src="__FILE_PATH__" width="100%" height="750px;"></iframe>
```

The implementation looks like:

```
var content = getIframeSelectionText(document.getElementById("iframeId"));
```

What I get is the text selected. I need `HTML`(because I want to catch the images too)

I tried adding `.html()` to `getSelection()` but didn't work.
Solution can involve `jQuery` too.

How to go forward?

**---EDIT---**

A close hint is found here: [window.getSelection() gives me the selected text, but I want the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139616/window-getselection-gives-me-the-selected-text-but-i-want-the-html)

A reference to the `Selection` object in question is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

**---POSSIBLE SOLUTION---**

Here is a solution to the similar(not the same) problem I'm facing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/124929/2284357
and another one is [Get Selected HTML in browser via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083682/get-selected-html-in-browser-via-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This returns the selected text node

```
let node = iframe.contentWindow.getSelection().baseNode
```

which afterwards can be used to get the parent node HTML

```
let html = node.parentElement.innerHTML
```

Comment: Thanks. However not all the contents selected are inside `.baseNode` In my case I'm getting the top most HTML only.

Comment: Rather which part contains the selected HTML in `Selection` object will be helpful. Or how to get parse the object.

Comment: The selection object doesn't contain the actual HTML, it can be casted to string using `getSelection().toString()` but in order to get the HTML itself you should use either baseNode, focusNode, anchorNode or extendNode provided on the selection object

Comment: Good hint. `toString()` returns text only. HTML can be found between `anchorNode` and `focusNode`

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on the right path...

```
$("body").on("click","#iframeId",function(){ 
    $(this).contents().find("html").html();
```

Comment: Pardon my knowledge in JS. is the `"load"` for `onload` event? I actually need it for `click` event and html of the selection by mouse.

Comment: Sorry, not sure why i'd assumed you might be trying to gather the html on load. Here's a click option... $("body").on("click","#iframeId",function(){

Comment: I've updated the answer to with this click modification. I'm assuming that you are trying to get the html content of #iframeID when the user clicks it.

Comment: So far it's working. But as in my question I'm actually looking for the html of the user selection. I think a variable should be inserted inside `find()` As I'm not trying to grab the whole HTML.

Comment: Sorry. Your original question was a bit vague for me to understand. You can specify the element, class or id you are wanting to locate inside .find(). Example: $(this).find('#bookmark');

Comment: Great. I just want to know how to make this `#bookmark` a variable of user mouse selection. Like `win.getSelection()` but in current context, which will work.

Comment: @NirjharLo I'm trying to assist, but you haven't provided a html example that I can play with to understand what a user might have SELECTED inside of this iframe.

Comment: Pasted a piece of HTML. Please see if you can give me some guidance.

Comment: Is this iframe url hosted on another domain? or same domain but different port number?

Comment: The iframe and the `src` both are in same domain. The image is however from a different domain.